# Postgresql Query equivalent to VLookUp of Excel

Tags: postgresql, join

I have two tables such as **Table1** and **Table2**. Table1 contains three columns called **name**, **age** and **marks** where marks column is empty and I need to populate from Table2. Table2 contains two column called **name_en** and **marks**. Note that Table1 is populated with more rows than Table2 and in the end result few rows can be blank. Its similar to VLookUp function of Excel. I am trying the following query.

```
INSERT INTO Table1(marks)
SELECT * FROM Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1
ON Table1.name = Table2.name_en
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't use a DBMS as an Excel spreadsheet. First, name your tables with names, accordingly to their use. "table1" and "table2" mean nothing. Second, there is no need to store information twice in the database. You can very well get all the info you need, when you need it, with the appropriate query, often a join. Example: `SELECT u.name, u.age, m.marks FROM table1 AS u LEFT JOIN table2 AS m ON m.name_en = u.name ;`  (No column "marks" in table1 needed at all. I assume that table1 has "users" info and table2 has "marks" info.)

Comment: I actually need the Marks in that table

Comment: Perhaps you do. We cannot be convinced that this is the best when you name the tables with "tableX".

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET marks = (SELECT Table2.marks FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.name_en = name)
```

You want to update all the rows of Table1 with the value of marks in Table2.

For each row of Table1, we get the column `marks` value for the name_en found in Table2 and set the `marks` column of Table1 with this value.

Comment: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000

Comment: So, you have many rows for a same name in Table2. What should Postgres do with those multiple rows ?